# Why is Quark Naturally Fat Free

Tags: nutrition

Why is Quark "Naturally Fat Free"?

http://groceries.iceland.co.uk/grahams-quark-naturally-fat-free-250g/p/66581

Low-fat or fat-free products often have the stigma that they have been "made so" through some form of "processing" which in turn removes certain desirable aspects of the food (vitamins, minerals), or adds other undesirable ones (sugar, thickener), do compensate for the removal of the fat component. So a claim that something is "naturally" fat-free sounds appealing.

But how can quark be naturally fat-free, when other dairy products are not?

Is it just a marketing ploy?

An example:

You start with full fat milk, you add rennet, you get curds, you drain the whey, you get cheese. Considered naturally high fat.
You start with full fat milk, you add some lactic bacteria, you get yoghurt. Considered naturally (relatively) high fat (to the extent that we now "make" low-fat ones).
You start with full fat milk, you add some other lactic bacteria, you get quark. Which is now magically, naturally fat free? How so? Where did the fat go? Is the whey that is drained out in some versions of quark full of cream? Hardly.

Some Wikipedia research yielded:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_(dairy_product)

> [some type of quark] contains in its basic form about 0.2% fat. Quark with higher fat content is made by adding cream

and

> In general, dry mass of quark has 1% to 40% fat; most of the rest is protein (80% of which is casein), calcium, and phosphate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with food labelling laws/common practice in Iceland, but in Australia we're bound by rules set out by [Food Standards Australia and New Zealand](http://www.foodstandards.gov.au/industry/labelling/Pages/default.aspx). On our ingredients lists, if the product is made with what was originally full-fat milk, it's entry on the ingredients list will be 'Milk' or 'Milk Solids'. If it's made with low fat/skim milk, it will be listed as 'Skim Milk' (though this could just be companies electing to declare they've used low-fat options to increase consumer appeal).

While I'm no cheesemaker, I do make my own low-fat yoghurt just by using skim milk (and our commercially available low-fat yoghurts list 'skim milk' on their ingredients lists). According to  Given that this is a particular brand of quark, and quark has a varied amount of fat in it according to the wiki article, I'd say that the manufacturer simply makes the cheese out of low-fat/skimmed milk and either doesn't have to or chooses not to declare as such on the ingredients list (the one you linked to simply said 'milk').

The fat doesn't go anywhere, its likely that it just wasn't there to begin with.